# Canvas drawImage with Coffeescript

Tags: canvas, coffeescript, html5-canvas

I want to draw an image on a canvas, then animate the image, rather like a sprite. I am having trouble making the image appear using Coffeescript. I have shortened my class for this posting; hopefully I did not introduce errors.

```
class TripleSlider
  @imageMin = new Image()

  constructor: (@context, @x, @y, @tsLabel, @showLimits=false) ->

  $(TripleSlider.imageMin).onload = -> 
    @context.drawImage(TripleSlider.imageMin, @x+50, @y+50)

  TripleSlider.imageMin.src = "/images/sliderTipMin.png"
```

I also tried writing the onload handler like this:

```
  TripleSlider.imageMin.onload = -> 
    @context.drawImage(TripleSlider.imageMin, @x+50, @y+50)
```

1. I suspect the onload handler syntax is somehow incorrect. Most of the examples I have found have been way more complex than is required, and the Coffescript docs leave a lot to the imagination.
2. How should I change the position of the image?

Mike

Answer (score 1):

`@`, or `this`, is not your `TripleSlider` instance inside your onload handler, so `@context` will probably not be defined. This is because of how javascript scopes `this`. Coffeescript provides the "[fat arrow](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow)", `=>`, for exactly this:

```
$(TripleSlider.imageMin).onload = =>
  @context.drawImage(TripleSlider.imageMin, @x+50, @y+50)
```

Comment: I tried that, but no joy. There is probably another problem as well. This also did not work:    $(TripleSlider.imageDef).load (event) =>
    @context.drawImage(TripleSlider.imageDef,  @x+63, @sliderTrackBottom())